# MongoDB: trying to read Long from JSON causes java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Tags: java, json, mongodb, mongodb-java

I have a code that reads data in a specific format from MongoDB. I need to test it.

In order to do so, I create a JSON with the data I want to test:

```
{
  "id": ObjectId("57552e32e4b0839ede67e0af"),
  "serial" : 574000690,
  "startDate" : ISODate("2016-08-22T23:01:56.000Z"),
  "endDate" : ISODate("2016-10-22T22:01:56.000Z"),
  "reason": ""
}
```

This is the object that supposed to be created:

```
public static class MyObject implements Serializable{
    private String id;
    private long serial;
    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;
    private String reason;
}
```

I have a code that reads a JSON file and creates a Mongo document, and write to a DB:

```
List<Document> docs = dirAsDbObjects(dir + File.separator + 
subDir.getName()).collect(Collectors.toList());

docs.forEach(docManipulator);
docs.forEach(doc -> doc.putIfAbsent("_id", new ObjectId()));

ret.addAll(docs);

MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase(dbName);
MongoCollection<Document> coll = db.getCollection(subDir.getName());

List<InsertOneModel<Document>> inserts = docs.stream().map(InsertOneModel::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
coll.bulkWrite(inserts);
```

Once the data is written, there's a code that tries to read the data from MongoDB and populate it into a `MyObject` instance:

```
    public MyObject(Document doc) {
        id = doc.getObjectId(DBConstants.ID).toString();
        serial = doc.getLong(DBConstants.SERIAL);
        startDate = doc.getDate("startDate");
        reason = doc.getString("source");
    }
```

Which fails on a error message:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

Because of the line `serial = doc.getLong(DBConstants.SERIAL);`. It basically gets the number from my JSON as "Integer" thus unable to read it as long.

I've tried the following line, and it works:

```
Long.parseLong(doc.get(DBConstants.SERIAL).toString())
```

But is it the best solution here? Will `.toString()` always gets me the string representation of a number? Is there a way to keep a number in JSON that would cause it to be read as `Long`?

**Update:**

@glytching gave an excellent answer!

I also discovered another way, apparently if you wrap the numerical elemnt of JSON in `NumberLong` it will be parsed as `Long` when translated from Mongo document.

So using the old code, I was able to make it work by changing my JSON like so:

```
{
  "id": ObjectId("57552e32e4b0839ede67e0af"),
  "serial" : NumberLong(574000690),
  "startDate" : ISODate("2016-08-22T23:01:56.000Z"),
  "endDate" : ISODate("2016-10-22T22:01:56.000Z"),
  "reason": ""
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Mongo Java driver has determined that the value of `serial` can 'fit' in an INT32 so it treats it as such. When you invoke `doc.getLong()` you are asking the driver to cast its Integer to a Long, hence the class cast exception. If, for example, the value of `serial` was `2147483648` (i.e. the max integer value + 1) then the Mongo Java driver would deem that to be an INT64 and you could then safely invoke `doc.getLong()`.

So, since (a) you have modelled this attribute as a `Long` in your class model and (b) not every persisted value of this attribute requires storage as an `INT64` ... you have to be sensitive to its persisted type when converting it into a Long.

How? Well, as long as the `serial` attribute is persisted as some sort of number (e.g. `INT32`, `INT64`) then this call ...

```
doc.get(DBConstants.SERIAL)
```

... will always return an object which is some subclass of `java.lang.Number` and therefore casting to `Number` and using `longValue()` will work.

For example:

```
serial = ((Number) doc.get(DBConstants.SERIAL)).longValue()
```