# What is the reason for JPA Repository giving a cast exception from Integer to Long in this particular scenario?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

> Edit : This piece of code is a patch to migrate data from MongoDb to
> Postgres. Please don't get confused with that

The JPA Repository is defined as follows

```
public interface PostgresUserGroupRepository extends JpaRepository<UserGroup, String> {

}
```

The entity class is as follows

```
@Data
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Entity
@Table(name = TableInfo.USER_GROUP)
@Builder
public class UserGroup implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    String id;

    @Column(length = 50, unique = true, nullable = false, name = "user_name")
    String userName;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = TableInfo.GROUP_ID_LIST, joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_name", referencedColumnName = "user_name"))
    @Column(name = "group_id")
    List<Long> groupIds = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

The user document within mongoDB is as follows. (The groupIds are of type int64)

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("594e597afa4f8c000102c388"),
    "userName" : "root",
    "groupIds" : [ 
        0,
        1,
        2
    ]
}
```

The driver code is as follows

```
//This gives an iterator over list of user documents
MongoCursor<Document> iterator = mymongoDB.getCollection("user").find().iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
//No issues in this casting
UserGroup userGroup = UserGroup.builder().groupIds((List<Long>) user.get("groupIds"))
                .userName(user.getString("userName")).build();
**//This line for storing to postgres giving the exception as shown below**
postgresUserGroupRepository.save(userGroup);
}
```

I am showing the whole stacktrace I got.

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:541)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:746)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:714)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:534)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:305)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:138)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy85.saveAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.patch.user.UserPatch.patchUsers(UserPatch.java:80)
    at com.patch.user.UserPatch.main(UserPatch.java:43)
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convertCommitException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:107)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:532)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.LongTypeDescriptor.unwrap(LongTypeDescriptor.java:19)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BigIntTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(BigIntTypeDescriptor.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:276)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.writeElement(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:911)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1334)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionRecreateAction.execute(CollectionRecreateAction.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:478)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:356)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1454)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:511)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3290)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2486)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:104)
    ... 19 more
```

Comment: I don't understand. Do you use Mongo or JPA?

Comment: An `Integer` isn't a `Long` nor is a `Long` and `Integer` so no you cannot cast one to the other. You would need to convert the int to a long or vice-versa.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli This is a  patch to migrate data from mongo to postgres. user is a collection in MongoDB.

Comment: @M.Deinum The exact same code was working fine in other systems. We are casting the object that we got from mongoDB with the get("key") method to a List<Long>. No issues in that as well. But when we try to persist it with the save() method of JPA, there we are getting this exception

Comment: Because an Integer isn't a Long and that will not work... The cast "works" (it actually hides this error) until you save it and then the list content needs to be transformed from an Integer into a Long (but as it is typed as long this fails). This code simply cannot work regardless what you state on other systems (those must have been different). What you need to do is transform all elements in the list into the result you want so if you get an `Integer` you need to iterate over those elements and convert them to `Long`. Casting the list to a list of longs isn't transforming them.

Comment: @M.Deinum I got it what you said. in mongoDb we have the groupIDs stored as int64. While getting that list usings user_collection.get("groupIds") we get it as an object. So I was casting it to a (List<Long>). If that can't be done how can we get a list of values within a MongoDB document inside our java code. 
The document structure is the same as I shown in question, I want to get that List of groupIDs in my java code. How can I do that. Can you please help me with that? It will save my day. Thank you for your time

Comment: @JithinMV the question is why does MongoDB return a list of Integer when you say that you store 64-Bit values. Bc. even if we show you how to convert, you might lose data that way!
I guess in `user.get` the `user` is a `Document`? (Bc. you didn't include that).

Comment: The docs also say that int64 -> Long: https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/java/sync/current/fundamentals/data-formats/documents/#document

You can also use the debugger (or print `getClass()`) to check the element type if the list contains at least one value. The type safe BsonDocument would also allow you to inspect element types: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.3/apidocs/bson/org/bson/BsonDocument.html

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution for this issue. Casting the Object returned from mongo to Number and then get it's long value. That will work

[The solution is discussed in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47121602/mongodb-trying-to-read-long-from-json-causes-java-lang-integer-cannot-be-cast-t)